# Script dosen't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This works fine in all the other browsers except for IE. Even in IE10 it doesn't want to cooperate. Any help would be appreciated. I have a form with a drop down menu that when different a user makes a selection it brings up a div with a different form we have 10 forms in all that they can choose from. Right now it does nothing in IE, no console errors or anything.

**Script**

```
var sections = {
    'second': 'section2',
    'third': 'section3',
    'forth': 'section4',
    'fifth': 'section5',
    'sixth': 'section6',
    'seventh': 'section7',
    'eigth': 'section8',
    'ninth': 'section9',
    'tenth': 'section10',
    'eleventh': 'section11'
};

var selection = function (select)
{
    for (i in sections)
    document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(sections[select.value]).style.display = "block";
}
$("#target option")
    .removeAttr('selected')
    .find(':first')
    .attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The HTML

```
    <select id="forms" onchange="selection(this);">
    <option >Select an option</option>
     <option value="tenth">General Inquiry</option>
        <option value="second">Account Inquiry</option>
        <option value="third">ARC Request</option>
        <option value="forth">Contact Information Update</option>
        <option value="fifth">Contact your Board</option>
        <option value="sixth">Document Request</option>
        <option value="seventh">Maintenance Issue Reporting</option>
          <option value="eigth">Violations Reporting</option>
           <option value="ninth">Closing Statement</option>
            <option value="eleventh">Request for Proposal</option>


    </select>
```

Then 11 divs

```
    <div id="section10" style="display:none;">
 <h2>General Inquiry</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: "Any help would be appreciated" - Yes, we'd like help on things such as "what doesn't work?", "what errors do you get", etc.

Comment: It would help if you could tell what "dosen't work" means. Are there errors in the console? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: @alex23 That's not necessary.

Comment: Yep, please create a JSFiddle with this case !

Comment: The JavaScript is just wrong in many ways

Comment: Don't expect any one to help you without giving an error for the scenario. People don't have ESP

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById` when you (apparently) have `jQuery` loaded?

Comment: @Jack thanks for your comment and for pointing out my mistake. I was mislead by my IDE (and stackoverflow syntax highlighting?), by the fact that there is an `Option` keyword, and by [this website](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm) when I ran a quick search. I've removed the answer because it wasn't right and so that its upvotes don't make readers believe that it's right :D

Answer (score 1):

Your problems turns out to be that [`selection` has special meaning inside IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For your code, IE produces following error

```
SCRIPT5002: Function expected
```

Which tells something about the issue.

A workaround to prevent this issue is to change your function name, like

```
var selectionFunc = function (select){...}
```

and in your markup,

```
<select id="forms" onchange="selectionFunc(this);">
....
</select>
```

I hope it helps